# Google Analytics outbound links and CRTL for new tab

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am using Google Universal Analytics to track outbound links, and it Works fine. But users can no longer open links in a new tab by pressing the Ctrl key while clicking on a link.

The script looks like this:

```
var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
    ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, { 
        'hitCallback': function () {
            document.location = url;
        }
    });
}
```

and a link looks like this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.example.com'); return false;">Check out example.com</a> `
```

Any help would be highly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a Javascript function if the user use "oben in new Tab" (right-click on a link). Its because the context-menu don't have any callbacks in javascript (unless you create your own context-menu).

But if you want that ctrl-key is working you can try this:

```
 <a href="http://www.example.com" class="checklink">Check out example.com</a>
```

Javascript with jquery

```
$(".checklink").on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var keypress = false;
    if(event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) { keypress = true;} // Mac and windows

    var url = $(this).prop("href");

    ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, { 
    'hitCallback': function () {
        if(keypress) {
           window.open(url);
        }else{
           document.location = url;
        }

    }
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks, for the information. Your example could be usefull, but since I don't use jquery it would be overhead to include this just to be able to track links. So I guess its a choice between being able to track outbound links or have a userfriendly site where users can choose if they want to open in a new tab or not.